# Composition of bicartesian squares

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

A commutative square is called bicartesian when it is both pull-back and push-out.
In an abelian category, consider two pull-back squares $(X)$ and $(Y)$: 
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
A & \longrightarrow & B & \longrightarrow & C \\
\downarrow & (X) & \downarrow & (Y) & \downarrow \\
D & \longrightarrow & E & \longrightarrow & F
\end{array}
$$

Prove that:

The square $(X+Y)$ is a bicartesian square $\Longleftrightarrow$
 The squares $(X)$ and $(Y)$ are bicartesian squares.

I have been able to prove, R.H.S $\Longrightarrow$ L.H.S but I am not being able to prove the other way. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that this is true? Don't you want to assume that some of these arrows are mono or epi?

Comment: If you assume that $X+Y$ and one between the two $X$ and $Y$ is bicartesian, then so is the other. This said, the claim as it is stated seems false ($C=A$ and $A\to B\to A$ the identity, $F=D$ and $D\to E\to D$ the identity; this is both a pullback and a pushout, but...)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by labeling the arrows:$\require{AMScd}$

$$
\begin{CD}
A @>f>> B @>g>> C\\
@VVaV @VVbV @VVcV\\
D @>>h> E @>>k> F
\end{CD}
$$

The square $(X+Y)$ is exact if and only if the "diagonal sequence" $0 \to A \xrightarrow{(gf, a)^t} C \oplus D \xrightarrow{(-c,kh)} F \to 0$ is exact.

The squares $(X)$ and $(Y)$ are pull-backs if and only if the "diagonal sequences" $0 \to A \xrightarrow{(f,a)^t} B \oplus D \xrightarrow{(b,-h)} E$ and $0 \to B \xrightarrow{(g,b)^t} C \oplus E \xrightarrow{(c,-k)} F$ are (left) exact.

So, assuming that $(X+Y)$ is exact and $(X)$ and $(Y)$ are pull-backs, we can conclude that $(Y)$ is exact since $(c,-k) \circ (1\oplus h) = (c,-kh)$ is epic, so $(c,-k)$ is epic and hence $(Y)$ is exact.

Now we know that $(X+Y)$ and $(Y)$ are both exact and it follows that so is $(X)$ by the fact mentioned by tetrapharmakon.